# How to explode each row that is an Array into columns in Spark (Scala)?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, etl

I have a Spark DataFrame with the a single column 'value', whereby each row is an Array of equal length. How can I explode this single 'value' column into multiple columns, which follow a schema like this?

[Single-column DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmRJf.png)

```
val bronzeDfSchema = new StructType()
  .add("DATE", IntegerType)
  .add("NUMARTS", IntegerType)
  .add("COUNTS", StringType)
  .add("THEMES", StringType)
  .add("LOCATIONS", StringType)
  .add("PERSONS", StringType)
  .add("ORGANIZATIONS", StringType)
  .add("TONE", StringType)
  .add("CAMEOEVENTIDS", StringType)
  .add("SOURCES", StringType)
  .add("SOURCEURLS", StringType)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work just fine

```
val schema=Seq(("DATE",0),("NUMARTS",1),("COUNTS",2),("THEMES",3),("LOCATIONS",4),("PERSONS",5),("ORGANIZATIONS",6),("TONE",7),("CAMEOEVENTIDS",8),("SOURCES",9),("SOURCEURLS",10))

val df2=schema.foldLeft(df)((df,x)=>df.withColumn(x._1,col("value").getItem(x._2)))
```

After you do this just cast the column into the data type you want.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I'm fairly new to Scala so what does the x._1 mean? How is it different from e.g. x(0)?

Comment: Welcome, it is the first element of the tuple.